# How to use typeface-open-sans with styled-components sheet.collectStyles?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have a [create-react-app](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-app) React app [configured](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#server-side-rendering) for SSR using `sheet.collectStyles`.

How can add CSS from [typeface-open-sans](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typeface-open-sans) so it is collected by `sheet.collectStyles`?

```
import "typeface-open-sans"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was approaching this problem from the wrong angle...

[create-react-app](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-app) already adds styles from `import "typeface-open-sans"` to `*.chunk.css` by default (which means they are available to the browser even when JavaScript is disabled).

No need to use `sheet.collectStyles`.